# Как обозначить доходчиво усвоенный материал?

Tags: лексика

Возможны ли следующие варианты обозначения процесса запоминания усвоенной информации?

1. В голове укладывается.
2. Ложится на ум.
3. Кладется на ум.
4. Улеглось в голове.
5. Разлеглось в уме.

Comment: Как назвать фразу без знаков препинания? Она ложится на ум?

Comment: @Владимир На будущее: если нужно перейти на новую строку, в конце предыдущей строки поставьте два пробела.